# setAttribute onclick event is not setting and run before the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, events

I'm creating a crud table through array objects, two fields name, and class and a submit button adds both fields with two buttons edit and delete, when I add set attribute on click to delete button it runs on the event add button, not the delet button.

i tried `document.getElementById(xyz).setAttribute('onclick', function)` it's not solving my problem.

I want to run the function when del button is pressed and the required event will be raised.

```js
var arobj = [];

function load(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var name = document.createElement("td");
    var classN = document.createElement("td");

    var nameValue = document.createTextNode("");
    var classN = document.createTextNode("");
  }
}

function addStudent(idn, idc, tab) {
  var obj = {};

  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var name = document.createElement("td");
  var classN = document.createElement("td");

  var nameValue = document.createTextNode(
    document.getElementById(idn).value
  );
  obj.nameVal = nameValue;
  var classValue = document.createTextNode(
    document.getElementById(idc).value
  );
  obj.classVal = classValue;

  arobj.push(obj);

  row.setAttribute("id", (arobj.length - 1).toString());

  var del = document.createElement("button");
  del.innerHTML = "delete";
  var edit = document.createElement("button");
  edit.innerHTML = "edit";
  var act = document.createElement("td");

  del.setAttribute("id", "btn" + (arobj.length - 1).toString());
  var delbtn = del.getElementById("btn" + (arobj.length - 1));
  console.log(delbtn);
  act.appendChild(del);

  act.appendChild(edit);
  name.appendChild(nameValue);
  classN.appendChild(classValue);
  row.appendChild(name);
  row.appendChild(classN);
  row.appendChild(act);
  document.getElementById(tab).appendChild(row);
  console.log(arobj);
  console.log(row.getAttribute("id"));
}

function delet() {
  alert("function ran");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="javascript:void(0)" onsubmit="addStudent('name','classN','table');">
  name:
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> <br /> class:
  <input type="text" name="classN" id="classN" /> <br />

  <input type="submit" value="add" />
</form>
<table id="table" border="2px solid black">
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>class</th>
    <th>action</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) use:

```
  var delbtn = document.getElementById("btn" + (arobj.length - 1));
```

instead of:

```
 var delbtn = del.getElementById("btn" + (arobj.length - 1));
```

2) also add code:

```
del.addEventListener('click', delet);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified some code, please see the comment following, BTW: it is efficient to use jQuery, react, Vue  etc.. libraries when solve this Dom data.

```
function addStudent(idn, idc, tab) {
    var obj = {};

    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var name = document.createElement("td");
    var classN = document.createElement("td");

    var nameValue = document.createTextNode(
      document.getElementById(idn).value
    );
    obj.nameVal = nameValue;
    var classValue = document.createTextNode(
      document.getElementById(idc).value
    );
    obj.classVal = classValue;

    arobj.push(obj);

    row.setAttribute("id", (arobj.length - 1).toString());

    var del = document.createElement("button");
    del.innerHTML = "delete";
    var edit = document.createElement("button");
    edit.innerHTML = "edit";
    var act = document.createElement("td");

    del.setAttribute("id", "btn" + (arobj.length - 1).toString());       
    var delbtn = document.getElementById("btn" + (arobj.length - 1));

    // here delbtn is null, it have not add to document yet!;
    console.log('delbtn',delbtn);

    act.appendChild(del);

    act.appendChild(edit);
    name.appendChild(nameValue);
    classN.appendChild(classValue);
    row.appendChild(name);
    row.appendChild(classN);
    row.appendChild(act);
    document.getElementById(tab).appendChild(row);
    console.log(arobj);
    console.log(row.getAttribute("id"));

    // delbtn is ready now;
    delbtn = document.getElementById("btn" + (arobj.length - 1));
    console.log('delbtn',delbtn);   // here is ok

    //add click event
    del.addEventListener("click",delet);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind event click to del button after you add the row into DOM:

```js
var arobj = [];
function load(arr) {
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var row = document.createElement("tr");
      var name = document.createElement("td");
      var classN = document.createElement("td");

      var nameValue = document.createTextNode("");
      var classN = document.createTextNode("");
    }
}

function addStudent(idn, idc, tab) {
    var obj = {};

    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var name = document.createElement("td");
    var classN = document.createElement("td");

    var nameValue = document.createTextNode(
      document.getElementById(idn).value
    );
    obj.nameVal = nameValue;
    var classValue = document.createTextNode(
      document.getElementById(idc).value
    );
    obj.classVal = classValue;

    arobj.push(obj);

    row.setAttribute("id", (arobj.length - 1).toString());

    var del = document.createElement("button");
    del.innerHTML = "delete";
    var edit = document.createElement("button");
    edit.innerHTML = "edit";
    var act = document.createElement("td");

    del.setAttribute("id", "btn" + (arobj.length - 1));

    act.appendChild(del);
    act.appendChild(edit);
    name.appendChild(nameValue);
    classN.appendChild(classValue);
    row.appendChild(name);
    row.appendChild(classN);
    row.appendChild(act);
    document.getElementById(tab).appendChild(row);

    document.getElementById("btn" + (arobj.length - 1)).addEventListener('click', delet);
}

function delet() {
    let row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
    alert("function ran");
}
```

```html
    <form
      action="javascript:void(0)"
      onsubmit="addStudent('name','classN','table');">
      name:
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> <br />
      class:
      <input type="text" name="classN" id="classN" /> <br />

      <input type="submit" value="add" />
    </form>
    <table id="table" border="2px solid black">
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>class</th>
        <th>action</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
```